# PCB design for alternating current and direct current on one big fr4 sheet

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I want to design a PCB dimensions Lenth= 1mtrs., Breath= 0.5 mtrs. and Thickness= 0.01 mtrs.For alternating part my load will draw maximum current of 25 amps and for DC purpose maximum drawn current is 10 amps. This designed pcb will mostly have tracks which will conduct the current to the load.

Once the design takes its physical shape I plan to power up multiple electrical devices.

What all design parameters should i take care when I am performing such kind of design as well as efficient grounding methods for such cases?

What type of losses are we talking here including EMC's between AC tracks and DC tracks?

Can voltage drop condition occur in my PCB as the dimensions what I am talking about is way bigger than normal?

If I want to do the load testing once my PCB is ready, how can I perform the load testing, any suggestions?

Comment: Too many questions and some are not answerable especially the EMC one.

Comment: That is going be be a *very* expensive, *very* custom PCB with those dimensions ...

Comment: @Andyaka atleast can I know the answers for few, starting with track width on FR4 substrate?

Comment: @brhans as of today what I want to test is the possibility of such kind of design, when you say expensive what is the exact "expensive" part we are talking about? is it the curring method or deposition, or availability of such kind of big sheet?

Comment: There are plenty of track thickness calculators on line. Just google "PCB track thickness calculator".

Comment: A 10mm thick board? Mainly current conduction? You don't need a board, you need a wiring harness.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: @W5VO - or BusBars

Comment: @W5VO yeah true , however what I want to know is can something be realized on PCB design or not!!

Comment: I can take a guess at how many spools of wire capable of handling 25A you can buy for the price of one 1m x 0.5m board. The board thickness is a bizzare requirement. Don't forget that when asking if you *can* do something, you should also ask if you *should* do it that way as well.

Comment: -1 for SHOUTING in the question's title.

Comment: @W5VO I totally agree with you and respect the thought, just for sake of testing; and understand actual constraints ; i wanted to design such kind of PCB. Purely experimental purpose.

Comment: @FakeMoustache apologies

Comment: You can edit your title any time you want.

Comment: All your questions can and will be answered by yourself when you have **experience** with this. The gap between what **you know now** and what you **need to know** to make this board is too large. So you have too many questions, see irrelevant problems everywhere, don't see the problems which do require attention. So **get some PCB design experience first** or get someone with more experience. When joining a PCB design company they will not let you do this on your own right away. You would be assisting an experienced designer to learn how to do this.

Comment: You know the conductivity of copper and the dimensions of the tracks you want on your board. You can do the math to figure out the losses just as well as we can.

Comment: @FakeMoustache very true, I have very little experience in PCB domain; just the college experience and that to project related mostly. I will do some more ground work in parallel to understand the complexity

Comment: I did some quick searching and could not find anyone to manufacture anything that size, are you sure about how big you want this to be?

Comment: I sense it's bizzzare requirement by seeing the reaction of partcipants. However if this concept works then many applications can be derived out of this

Comment: I can't imagine any of the many applications, and I make my living dealing with power electronics.

Comment: @sarkar.shukla keep in mind that if you want to sell this design you have to pass regulatory compliance (in most countries). Its a good idea to know creepage and clearance distances https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/AN583.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What type of losses are we talking here including EMC's between AC tracks and DC tracks?

Radiative coupling between tracks depends on the exact pattern of the copper areas, and the frequencies present in the voltage or current signals. Capacitive coupling depends mainly on the proximity between neighboring tracks. Inductive coupling depends mainly on the overlap between current-carrying loops and victim loops. If you are operating below 100 kHz (including harmonic content in any signals), separate your tracks by at least 1 mm, and avoid coupled loops, you are not likely to have EMC issues.

> Can voltage drop condition occur in my PCB as the dimensions what I am talking about is way bigger than normal?

The conductivity of pure copper is about \$6\times 10^7\$ S/m. The conductivity of rolled annealed copper (what's actually present on a pcb) is slightly lower. Maybe figure 90% of this figure to be conservative.

Copper on a PCB is typically about 35 microns, but it can be made from 1/4 to maybe 5 or 6 times this thick, or more at some vendors.

From this and the dimensions of the tracks you want to make and the current you will be carrying you can find the voltage drop. Or you can set a target for voltage drop and find how wide you need to make your tracks.

> If I want to do the load testing once my PCB is ready, how can I perform the load testing, any suggestions?

Supply a large current through the track, measure the voltage dropped across it.

> I want to design a PCB dimensions Lenth= 1mtrs., Breath= 0.5 mtrs. and Thickness= 0.01 mtrs.

Flexible circuit materials can be processed by a roll-to-roll method, potentially allowing very long dimensions. But the thickness of these materials is typically 1 mm or less, not the 10 mm you're asking for. And the copper thickness allowed is limited to maintain the flexibility of the circuit. You'd likely need to work with a vendor to design a process to manufacture your particular design.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i think i got my starting point; will keep you all updated :)